# Listing Digital ocean droplet snapshots along with date of creation

Tags: command-line, digital-ocean, droplet

I am in need of situation where i need to list out the available droplet snapshot of specific droplet. I am using doctl to list the snapshots. I need a way that the doctl command needs to list out the available snapshots along with date of creation. Alternate solutions is also appreciated. I am not sure is this possible. It would be great help if some one render their hands to make it clear.

Thanks,
Muneesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

Do you wish to filter the list of snapshots by a given Droplet (ID)?

If so, I suspect you'll want to consider using `doctl --output=json` to get the `doctl` command's output as JSON and then use a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the result.

I created a Droplet and a snapshot and this works:

```sh
# jq filter
FILTER=".[]|select(.resource_id==\"${DROPLET}\")"

# For all my Droplets
DROPLETS=$(doctl compute droplet list --format=ID --no-header)

for DROPLET in ${DROPLETS}
do
  doctl compute snapshot list \
  --resource=droplet \
  --output=json \
  | jq "${FILTER}"
done
```

And, if you want to limit the output to just `name` and `created_at`:

```
FILTER=".[]|select(.resource_id==\"${DROPLET}\")|{\"name\":.name,\"created\":.created_at}"
```

Comment: Hi @DazWikin apreciated your efforts..let me give the scenerio...consider a droplet and it is having 3 snapshots. what i want is i need to list all the three snapshots along with time of creation using doctl in command line thats it

Comment: By the way  i am getting this error jq: error (at <stdin>:4729): Cannot index array with string "snapshot" when executing the above command

Comment: It should be `snapshots` not `snapshot`

Comment: Apologies... I just created a snapshot... There's no `snapshots` in the JSON output, I'll update the answer.

Comment: doctl compute snapshot list \
--resource=droplet \
--output=json \
| jq ".[]|select(.resource_id==\"${222153257}\")"

Comment: is that rite format ..could you please suggest?

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: `doctl compute snapshot list --resource=droplet --output=json | jq ".[]|select(.resource_id==\"222153257\")"`

Comment: quick question...the commented answer needs to be run as shell script rite? if yes the loop keeps executing and not ends

Comment: I added the `for` to show a simple way to obtain Droplet IDs. You need not use that. You just need to provide `doctl compute snapshot list` with a Droplet ID to filter.

Answer (score 0):

The command exists:

```bash
doctl compute snapshot list
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/compute/snapshot/list/).